# ColdFusion to Railo: Replace <cferror type="validation">

Tags: validation, error-handling, coldfusion, migration, railo

I've a ColdFusion application that has been using inbuilt Error-Handling technique for Form Validations using **cferror** tag with **type="validation"**. 
Currently, there are over 1k validations happening using this technique.

Unfortunately, this technique is not supported in Railo. I've been searching over the net for a feasible option for an alternate/manual method to this inbuilt form validation technique. And I'm unable to find the same to accomplish this task.

Any ideas on how should this functionality be implemented in Railo?

**Update as on 28/7/2015:** I've found that there is a way Railo could use the functionality of in-built Form Validation technique. In terms of Railo it is called as **RailoForms**. But, there's very little or no documentation available on net for the same. Does anyone have the information or have used this technique? Please suggest.

Really appreciate.. Thanks!

Comment: Could you instead use the error handler in the application.cfc and use something like notepad++'s regex replacement tool + it's find in files tool to comment them all out? (don't forget to back it up first..)

Comment: We've an Application.cfm at present. When we use the inbuilt technique, a Special field is being returned called **Error.InvalidFields** after the validation happens. It shows a message to the user for all the form validation errors. For migration to Railo, I thought I could use the onError method of Application.cfc but I'm not sure if I could do all the form validations that are being handled currently.

Comment: If you're desperate about using the validation errors in railo, you can try to build your own custom tag solution for it. One good post [here](http://www.boutonjones.com/pub/cferror.html) can be used as the base.

Comment: Thanks Anurag. I'll have a look at it & update the post. All I require is to do minimum changes in the current code so that there are no exceptions raised. Currently, if I just remove the validation cferror tag then no form inputs are validated and directly an attempt is made to enter values to database and this causes an exception.

Comment: Hi Anurag, I checked the post. Again, it makes use of in built error-handling technique. The only thing I could see is that they have improvized on the existing functionality.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your comments. I've updated the post with my findings. Do you know how to leverage the RailoForms functionality? @KevinB

Comment: Thanks Guys for your comments. I've updated the post with my findings. Do you know how to leverage the RailoForms functionality? @Anurag

Comment: Nope, never used any of coldfusion or railo's cfhtmlelement tags.

Comment: oh! Looks like I might have to write my own custom code then.